# how to change a word in a specific group using python?

Tags: python, text-processing

I need to change a word in a specific `define service` section where `service_description` is `NRPE - NTP_TIME` and where `contact_groups` is `ops1`, I need to change to `ops2` and I would like to do it to shorten my work because I need to do it on multiple hosts. Below is a snippet of the file; for example

```
  
define service{
        use                             generic-service

        service_description             NRPE
        is_volatile                     
        check_period                    
        max_check_attempts              
        check_interval           
        retry_interval            
        contact_groups                  xyz,xyz,ops1,xyz

        notification_period             24x7
        check_command                   xyz
        }
define service{
        use                             generic-service

        service_description             NRPE
        is_volatile                     
        check_period                    
        max_check_attempts              
        check_interval           
        retry_interval            
        contact_groups                  xyz,xyz,ops1,xyz

        notification_period             24x7
        check_command                   xyz
define service{
        use                             generic-service

        service_description             NRPE - NTP_TIME
        is_volatile                     
        check_period                    
        max_check_attempts              
        check_interval           
        retry_interval            
        contact_groups                  xyz,xyz,ops1,xyz

        notification_period             24x7
        check_command                   xyz
```

```
import re


with open("plik.txt", "r") as file:
    contents = file.read()


contents = re.sub(r"service_description.*NTP_TIME(\n.*)*contact_groups.*(ops1)", 
                  "service_description.*NTP_TIME\g<1>*contact_groups.*(ops2)", contents)


with open("plik.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(contents)
```

I don't quite know how to write this code, I mean that if the service description is NRPE - NTP_TIME then I would like to change ops1 to ops2 only here.

Comment: Why didn't you put the `line.replace` line *inside* the `if` statement?

Comment: my copying mistake.

Comment: So then your problem is solved, isn't it?

Comment: Except, now you also moved `f.write(line)` into the `if` statement. Why didn't you put that *outside* the `if` statement?

Comment: but this code won't change the word Ops 1 to Ops2 in the line where NRPE - NTP_TIME occurs? this word needs to be changed a few lines down. [code edited]

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex.

Read the content of your file, then use `replace` with a regex like `service_description.*NRPE - NTP_TIME\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*contact_groups.*(ops1)` to change `ops1` to `ops2`

Comment: what if in some define service the contact_group group will be on a different line (closer or farther from NTP_TIME) and could you be more specific about how to use it and where? ;)

Comment: You can change it to `service_description.*NTP_TIME(\n.*)*contact_groups.*(ops1)` to have arbitrary lines in between to make it agnostic of lines in between.

Comment: I have added changes to my post, can you please check and make changes?

Comment: added changes to my code* @code-lukas

Answer (score 0):

You can just use split function to iterate between services and replace the line you want after that.

Her you have a basic example:

```
with open('stackoverflow.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    lines_split = lines.split("define service{\n")
for i in range(len(lines_split)):
    if lines_split[i]:
        service_lines = lines_split[i].split("\n")
        # you can loop here to if you prefer
        if 'NRPE - NTP_TIME' in service_lines[2]:
            service_lines[8] = service_lines[8].replace('ops1', 'ops2')
            lines_split[i] = '\n'.join(service_lines)
print(lines_split)
lines = "define service{\n".join(lines_split)
# Now you can write lines to the file
with open("stackoverflow.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(lines)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't know if I did something wrong, but unfortunately it doesn't change this word in contact_groups from ops1 to ops2 ;(

Comment: Did you used the exact code above? i changed it XD

Comment: yes i used it, and of course changed stackoverflow.txt to my filename

Comment: change it to plik1.txt or the file you want to change. If the file is in the format you said in the question it must change to ops2 without any problems.

Comment: this file is just an example, originally there are more groups in contact_groups. if you understand what I mean

Comment: But all the services use the same format right (if they have diferent lines you can just replace the if statment with a for loop)? you can replace as mush contact grups you want and you can append more conditions if you want to change other services too. It doesn't change the output not matter how much grups you have. You can contact me on twitter if you prefer @gerardo_lodrich

Comment: could you edit your code and explain it to me? it honestly hurts my head.